# Find span tag in table in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<table id="mytable" runat="server">
        <tr class="csstablelisttd">
            <td>
                08:00
            </td>
            <td>
                00
            </td>
            <td>
                <span></span>
            </td>
        </tr>


  for(int i = 0; i < mytable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < mytable.Rows[i].Cells.Count; j++)
                    {

    }
}


if(mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"] != null && mytable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Attributes["class"].Equals("csstdgreen"))
                {
                    //For finding class of td.I use above code 
                }
```

I have to find span tag in table and have to add text in span tag.
which is in td of table.
i dont want to apply runat="server" because there are 50 span in my tabel.
i am looping through table like this.I have search google lot but didnt find anything in c#.
**i have to put value in span tag from database**
***Note : No Javascript or Jquery !***

Comment: Why can't you use Javascript? It would be the easiest solution.

Comment: i have to put value in span tag from database

Comment: @John is there a reason why you can't use a repeater to generate the table?

Comment: i use jquery from clicent side on this table

Comment: Then a `datalist` would be the best option here

Comment: i make 1000 line code for this thing how i make table in repeater for only find span tag in table

Comment: is building an asp Table an option? you can build your table form the code behind. A gridview or a repeater is actually a better choice for this. Any reason you dont want to use them?

Comment: What exactly are you doing with jQuery? I'm not sure why that would be a problem

Comment: i have to Find span tag in table in c# i dont want to use jquery and repeater else what i ask give the answer of that no options pls .............

Comment: Now start my question down voting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've got to use a `asp:Label` or put `runat="server"` on your `<span>` or generate your span from code-behind

```
 //Just an hint, can't remember the proper way to do this but you can

 myTable.Rows[i].Cells[last].InnerHtml = "<span>value</span>";
```

that gives you another option/idea

Comment: in td text it gives me like <span>value</span>

Comment: you can substitute your value into that. did you copy verbatim? I expected you to replace `value` with something else like `"<span>"+mycustomvaluetodisplayhere+"</span>"`

Comment: string kk = "john";
   mytable.Rows[i].Cells[2].InnerText = "<span>"+kk+"</span>";

Comment: result:<span>john</span>  in td text <td></td>

Comment: I have updated my answer. Use `InnerHtml` instead of InnerText. It worked on my side here

Answer (score 1):

When using jQuery, give all you span's a className and the TD an ID

```
<td id="idOfTd">
    <span class="className">Blabla</span>
</td>
```

In jQuery u can do the following:

```
var allSpans = $('#idOfTd .className');
```

Comment: i had not put tag jquery in my quetion

Comment: But you can add it into your project =)

Comment: i have to put  value in span tag from database so how is it possible??????????????

Comment: but you had not put tag 'database' in your question ;)

Comment: also i had not put client side scripting tag in quetion

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add text in span in code behind then as I know its too tuff without using runat="server". but if you want to add text in javascript then it can be done....by searching span using getElementusingTagName('span') inside td and add text to it.
For doing this in javascript you don't have need to give id to span as well as no need to write runat ="server".
below javascript code is written -

`<script type="text/javascript">
    function getInfo() 
    {
        var mygetTable = document.getElementById("<%=mytable.ClientID %>");
        for (var j = 0; j < mygetTable.rows.length; j++) 
        {
            var abc = mygetTable.rows[j].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span');
            abc[0].innerHTML = 'I am Span.';
        }
    }
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Give the TD or span an ID and add the data in it by code behind

Comment: dont want to apply runat="server" because there are 50 span in my tabel

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the server control, maybe javascript is a better idea to do this job.

Comment: i had not put tag jquery in my quetion

Answer (score 0):

Firstly give each span an unique id, say like the one given below...

```
<td>
<span id="span1"></span>
</td>
```

and then using javascript you can find this span and add the required text, some thing like

```
 document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'your required message can go here';
```

here is a small fiddle link to it = http://fiddle.jshell.net/fFHbf/

Comment: i had not put tag javascript in my quetion

Answer (score 0):

If you can set an id to each tag, you could do something like this:

HTML:

```
<span id="spanTagId"></span>
```

Then, with java script:

```
document.getElementById('spanTagId').innerHTML = 'Your text...';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add text in span in code behind then as I know its too tuff without using runat="server". but if you want to add text in javascript then it can be done....by searching span using getElementusingTagName('span') inside td and add text to it. For doing this in javascript you don't have need to give id to span as well as no need to write runat ="server". below javascript code is written -

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function getInfo() 
{ 
    var mygetTable = document.getElementById("<%=mytable.ClientID %>"); 
    for (var j = 0; j < mygetTable.rows.length; j++) 
    { 
        var abc = mygetTable.rows[j].cells[2].getElementsByTagName('span');
        abc[0].innerHTML = 'I am Span.'; 
    } 
 } 
 </script>
```

Comment: My dear friend question is abt in c#